# How to iterate over generic Map

Tags: java, generics, collections

I want to create a clone() method for the generic class containing generic map, but I'm stuck on iterating over the entryset of the map. Here's the important part:

```
private Map<Object, ObjectWrapper<E>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, ObjectWrapper<E>>();
for (Map.Entry<Object, ObjectWrapper<E>> entry: map.entrySet()){
    ....
}
```

The compiler error is this:

```
[ERROR] found   : java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Object,abc.ObjectWrapper<E>>
[ERROR] required: java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Object,abc.ObjectWrapper<E>>
```

Looks the same to me:)

I'm able to do the stuff by iterating over the keys and retrieve values inside the loop, but I'll get into trouble with Sonar. 
I've tried casting the result of map.entrySet() to a lot of things(like `Set<? extends<Map.Entry<Object, ObjectWrapper<E>>>)` as suggested in similar topics, but with no results:(

**EDIT:**
The problem was using the generic parameter in both the class and the method. 
For future reference, here's the SSCE(not working):

```
public class Test<E> {
private Map<Object, ObjectWrapper<E>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, ObjectWrapper<E>>();

public <E> Test<E> test(){
    for (Map.Entry<Object, ObjectWrapper<E>> entry: map.entrySet()){
    }
    return null;
}

private static class ObjectWrapper<T>{
}
```

}

Comment: Can you create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can see the error for ourselves?

Comment: You've not declared `E` twice or something have you? (Note iterating over a concurrent collection may not do exactly what you want.)

Comment: You probably have a `<E>` both in your class and method declarations and the latter hides the former.

Comment: Show the method signature containing that `for` loop.

Comment: I see. I've just removed the <E> from the method declaration and it works. Thanks to all and sorry for my stupidity :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code built up from your partial code works for me in java version 1.6.0_24 without any errors

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class CMap<E>{
  public CMap() {

  }
  public void test() {
    Map<Object, List<E>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, List<E>>();
    for (Map.Entry<Object, List<E>> entry: map.entrySet()){

    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CMap<Integer> cMap = new CMap<Integer>();
    cMap.test();
  }
}
```

its compiling and execution log:

```
$ javac CMap.java
$ java CMap
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is already solved. See comments and edit in the question.